# Where to store "factory defaults" configuration settings, so they may be updated programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The user of my Visual Studio application may click a button to restore the application  to the factory defaults. At the factory we configure the application and then click another button to set that configuration as the factory defaults to the present configuration settings.

However, if we save the configuration settings (XML format) to settings.settings, they are stored in our own user folder (not in the Visual Studio project folder), and the user doesn't receive them.

(settings.settings uses the default values stored at design time.)

We need to store the factory defaults in a file that is included in the executable, or distributed with it. We can write the factory defaults in a factorydefaultconfig.xml file included with the distribution, but I thought you may know of a better way of doing that.

Right now I am studying Application configuration files to see if that's what I should be using.

Answer (score 3):

Yep App Settings or rolling your own is the way we've handled this in the past.  Add a reference to System.Configuration to your project, and then use the following:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("lang", "English"); //Set
string getLang = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lang"]; //Get
```

For the App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="lang" value="English"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I got bogged down on writing XML to it (I already have all the settings rolled into a single XML string). I am actually "rolling my own": I am simply writing the string as is to the FactoryDefault.config file. I know it's not the right way, but I am so bogged down in figuring our the right way... I need to move on.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to try this out.  Here is a class I wrote called ConfigHub for doing just what you are talking about.  It makes use of locks as well, to ensure you don't end up with file in use errors:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 
using System.Xml;

public static class ConfigHub
{
    #region State
    private static string WorkingDirectoryVar = null;
    private static string ConfigFileNameVar = null;
    private static bool AutoRefreshVar = true;
    private static bool VerboseVar = true;
    private static bool SetupExecutedVar = false;
    private static XmlDocument ConfigDocVar = new XmlDocument();
    private static Dictionary<string, string> ConfigLookupPair = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private static Object ConfigHubLock = new Object();
    private const string CommentNameVar = "#comment";
    #endregion

#region Property
public static bool Verbose
{
    get { return VerboseVar; }
    set { VerboseVar = value; }
}
public static bool AutoRefresh
{
    get { return AutoRefreshVar; }
    set { AutoRefreshVar = value; }
}
public static bool SetupExecuted
{
    get { return SetupExecutedVar; }
}
public static string ConfigFilePath
{
    get { return WorkingDirectoryVar + @"\" + ConfigFileNameVar; }
}
public static string ConfigFileName
{
    get { return ConfigFileNameVar; }
}
public static string WorkingDirectory
{
    get { return WorkingDirectoryVar; }
}
#endregion

#region Setup
public static void Setup()
{
    lock (ConfigHubLock)
    {
        //Initialize config with default
        WorkingDirectoryVar = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        ConfigFileNameVar = "SCW.Config.xml";
        SetupExecutedVar = true;
        RefreshConfiguration();
    }
}
public static void Setup(string configFileName)
{
    lock (ConfigHubLock)
    {
        //Initialize config with specified file
        WorkingDirectoryVar = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        ConfigFileNameVar = configFileName.Trim().ToLower().Replace(".xml", "") + ".xml";
        SetupExecutedVar = true;
        RefreshConfiguration();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Merchant
public static void SetValue(string key, string value)
{
    //Fail if setup hasn't been called
    if (!SetupExecutedVar) throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.NotSetup, "Setup must be called before using the ConfigHub", null);        

    try
    {            
        lock (ConfigHubLock)
        {
            //Set the value 
            bool foundNode = false;
            foreach (XmlNode configNode in ConfigDocVar.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
            {
                if (configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower() == key.Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    configNode.InnerXml = value.Trim();
                    foundNode = true;
                }
            }
            if (!foundNode)
            {
                XmlNode newNode = ConfigDocVar.CreateNode("element", key.Trim(), "");
                newNode.InnerXml = value.Trim();
                ConfigDocVar.ChildNodes[0].AppendChild(newNode);
            }

            //Save the config file
            ConfigDocVar.Save(WorkingDirectoryVar + @"\" + ConfigFileNameVar);                
            RefreshConfiguration();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.SetValue, "Set value failed", err);
    }
}
public static string GetValue(string key)
{
    //Fail if setup hasn't been called
    if (!SetupExecutedVar) throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.NotSetup, "Setup must be called before using the ConfigHub", null);
    if (AutoRefreshVar) RefreshConfiguration();

    try
    {
        lock (ConfigHubLock)
        {
            //Get and return the value
            if (AutoRefreshVar) RefreshConfiguration();
            if (ConfigLookupPair.ContainsKey(key.Trim().ToLower()))
            {
                return ConfigLookupPair[key.Trim().ToLower()];
            }
            else
            {
                throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.NoKeyFound, "The key " + key + " was not found", null);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.GetValue, "Get value failed", err);
    }
}
public static void RefreshConfiguration()
{
    //Fail if setup hasn't been called
    if (!SetupExecutedVar) throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.NotSetup, "Setup must be called before using the ConfigHub", null);

    try
    {
        //Load configuration from file
        ConfigDocVar.Load(WorkingDirectoryVar + @"\" + ConfigFileNameVar);
        List<string> duplicateCheck = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode configNode in ConfigDocVar.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
        {
            if (configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower() == CommentNameVar)
            {
                //Ignore the Comment
            }
            else
            {
                if (duplicateCheck.Contains(configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower()))
                {
                    //Duplicate key failure
                    throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.DuplicateKey, "The key " + configNode.Name.Trim() + " appears multiple times", null);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add configuration key value pair
                    duplicateCheck.Add(configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower());
                    if (!ConfigLookupPair.ContainsKey(configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower()))
                    {
                        ConfigLookupPair.Add(configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower(), configNode.InnerXml.Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ConfigLookupPair[configNode.Name.Trim().ToLower()] = configNode.InnerXml.Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //Look form root missing and multiple roots
        if (err.ToString().ToLower().Contains("root element is missing"))
        {
            throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.NoRootFound, "No configuration root found", err);
        }
        else if (err.ToString().ToLower().Contains("multiple root elements"))
        {
            throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.MultipleRoots, "Multiple configuration roots found", err);
        }
        else
        {
            throw ConfigHubException.BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType.Refresh, "Refresh failed", err);
        }
    }
}
#endregion    
}

#region Exception
public enum ConfigHubExceptionType { NotSetup, Setup, Refresh, DuplicateKey, NoKeyFound, SetValue, GetValue, NoRootFound, MultipleRoots }
public class ConfigHubException : Exception
{
    public ConfigHubException(ConfigHubExceptionType errType, string message) : base("#" + errType.ToString() + "-" + message + (ConfigHub.ConfigFilePath != @"\" ? " (" + ConfigHub.ConfigFilePath + ")" : "")) { }
    public ConfigHubException(ConfigHubExceptionType errType, string message, Exception innerException) : base("#" + errType.ToString() + "-" + message + (ConfigHub.ConfigFilePath != @"\" ? " (" + ConfigHub.ConfigFilePath + ")" : ""), innerException) { }
    public static ConfigHubException BuildException(ConfigHubExceptionType exceptionType, string message, Exception innerException)
    {
        if (!ConfigHub.Verbose || innerException == null) return new ConfigHubException(exceptionType, message);
        else return new ConfigHubException(exceptionType, message, innerException);      
    }
}
#endregion
```

Note.  You need to build the file in your project first and remove the XML header.  Like the following (Ex: MyConfigFile.xml) - NO xml tag at the top like ().  Finally, make sure you set your xml config file to copy always:

```
<Config>
   <ValueName>Value</ValueName>
</Config>
```